# Matlab: Printing a data on a specific line

Tags: matlab, printf, fopen, fgets

I have below function:

```
function [] = Write(iteration)
status=close('all');
nomrep=num2str(iteration);
fid=fopen('ID.dat','a');
frewind(fid);
for l=1:iteration
   line=fgetl(fid); 
end
fprintf(fid,[nomrep,' \n']);
status=fclose(fid);
end
```

I expect that `Write(15)` creates ID.dat and prints 2 and 15 in consecutive lines at begining of line 15th.

But is prints those values always on the beginning of the file.

Even I tried `fgetl(fid)` alone, and also replaced for loop with while loop still did not work.

Is it due to the fact that I should fill in the lines before that with some dummy space? along side this, I executed

`for i=1:5
    Write(i);
end`

Which should print 1 to 5 in each line but even this does not work.

Comment: Online I found another way even that does not work


`function [] = Write2(iteration)`

`status=close('all');
nomrep=num2str(iteration);
fid=fopen('ID.dat','w');
tline = fgets(fid);
for l=1:iteration
    tline = fgets(fid);
end
fprintf(fid,[nomrep,' \n']);
status=fclose(fid);
end

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
fid=fopen('ID.dat','w');
```

Everytime you open the file, you are overwriting the previous contents (that is what the `'w'` argument does).  Change `'w'` to `'a'` (for append), and your file will retain the contents from one write to the next.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but still it does not for instance print 8 at line 8th under the function call `Write(8)`

Comment: It seems that if the file is empty matlab does not count the lines, so I thought of putting dummy alphabets let's say 'a' at each line, then print my desired parameter in the line that I like.
So below I print 'a' in all 20 lines:
`iteration=20;`
`fid=fopen('ID.dat','w');`
`for k=1:iteration`
   `fprintf(fid,'\n %s','a');`
`end`
`status=fclose(fid);`
`fclose('all');`
And now I call the function as Write(8), but again it does not print 8 at 8th line and prints it at the end of ID.dat file although I already resetted the line pointer by `frewind(fid);`